# Proper way to iterate over a dict value that may or may not be present in Python

Tags: python

Basically, if I'm trying to access a dict value which I expect to be an iterable is there an easy one-liner to account for that value not being present aside from using some like  DefaultDict. There's this

```
for el in (myDict.get('myIterable') or []):
    pass
```

Doesn't feel particularly pythonic though...

Comment: Are you trying to handle values which are not present in the array, or which may be None/False in the array? Your example code only handles the latter.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out meant to use .get, editing now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for item in a_dict.get("some_key",[]):
    #do whatever
```

if the item is guaranteed to be a list if present ... if it might be things other than a list you will need a different solution

Answer (score 3):

You can make a subclass of `dict` that provides a default value with the `__missing__(self, key)` method:

```
class EmptyIterableDict(dict):
def __missing__(self, key):
    return []
```

Example usage:

```
test = EmptyIterableDict()
test['a'] = [3,2,1]
test['b'] = [2,1]
test['c'] = [1]

for v in test['a']:
    print v

3
2
1

for v in test['d']:
    print v
```

If you already have a vanilla `dict` that you want to iterate like that over, you can make a temporary copy:

```
original = {'a': [1], 'b': [2,3]}

temp = EmptyIterableDict(original)
for v in temp['d']:
    print v
```

Comment: Don't bother subclassing `dict()` for something that trivial.  Just use a `collections.defaultdict(list)`.

Answer (score 1):

An explicit, multi-line approach to this would be:

```
if 'my_iterable' in my_dict:
    for item in my_dict['my_iterable']:
        print(item)
```

which could also be written as a one-line comprehension:

```
[print(item) for item in my_dict['my_iterable'] if 'my_iterable' in my_dict]
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a one-liner but it accounts for both possible failures.

```
try:
    for item in dictionary[key]:
        print(item)
except KeyError:
    pass  # Key wasn't present in the dictionary.
except TypeError:
    pass  # Key was present but corresponding item not iterable.
```

Comment: If you replace `print()` with some more elaborate function, this may catch exceptions you don't want to catch.